# Weird SQL exception when using single quotes in string

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm Sending messages to the server and updloading the messages to Data base,
Most of the words go through properly but i noticed that when i send the words 
"what's up?" It gives an error but when i send "whats up?" without the single comma between T and S it works good.

What is the problem?

This is the exception i get:
Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 's'.

Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'.

I get the exception at com.Executenonquery row.

```
string message = bf.Deserialize(client).ToString();
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand($"insert into messages (messagetext,sentdate) values ('{message}','{DateTime.Now}')",sc);
int success = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (success < 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong");
}
```

Comment: Use parameters!  Don't munge query strings with direct input.  You have just learned about SQL injection.  Just google it and learn a lot more about it.

Comment: Beside giving you protection from SQL injections, allow some performance improving, and much more, using parameters in query as @GordonLinoff suggests will help you a lot: no problem with date formatting, `'` within strings, and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string message = bf.Deserialize(client).ToString();
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insert into messages (messagetext,sentdate) values (@sqlMessage, @sqlDatetime)", sc);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sqlMessage", message);
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
var sqlFormattedDate = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sqlDataTime", sqlFormattedDate);

int success = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (success < 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong");
}
```

Adding parameters will fix your issue, you're adding the string as `'hello'` instead of `hello` for example

Comment: A side note. ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") format is not reliable under every date and language setting (especially if the version information is unknown). A better format would be  ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss") and better yet just let the parameter of type Date\DateTime or DateTime2 and let the driver handle that.

Answer (score 3):

You shoot yourself in the foot.

Your string:

```
$"insert into messages (messagetext,sentdate) values ('{message}','{DateTime.Now}')"
```

after you pass "what's up?" you get:

```
insert into messages (messagetext,sentdate) values ('what's up?','...')
```

see this part: `'what's up?'`? The apostrophe is also the quote for the strings in the SQL. That is the reason you should **NEVER PUT DATA IN SQL USING STRING OPERATIONS**. Use parameters or better an ORM.

Comment: I thought the main reason was to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: @jarlh well OP just SQL-injected themselves.

Answer (score 2):

You need to double the single quotes for that to work, but you should use parameterized queries instead. The sytem will handle everything for you and also check the content of the variables to prevent SQL Script Injection.

Comment: I upvoted your suggestion, however a slight correction. System wouldn't check the content of the variables. You are passing something as pure plain text and it would be stored as is (not executed - it can contain any script too).

Answer (score 1):

Because your input generates an invalid query like below..

```
insert into messages (messagetext,sentdate) values ('what's up?','somedate')
```

Did you observe the difference? your single quotation mark closes the opening quotation mark that started before word *what*. To work around this, it is always a best practice to use parameterized SQL.

Here is some reference

[SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are using single ' (single quote) instead of double and that acts as the end of the string literal there, making the SQL invalid. You should use parameters to:

1. Avoid SQL injection attack.
2. Avoid problems as you just encountered and more (like correctly formatted and passed date\datetime values).

Also in your code checking result value like that is useless, since you would get an exception. Revised code:

```
int rows = 0;
string message = bf.Deserialize(client).ToString();
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(@"insert into messages 
   (messagetext,sentdate) 
   values 
   (@message, @sent)", sc);
com.Parameters.Add("@message",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = message;
com.Parameters.Add("@sent",SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value=DateTime.Now;
try
{           
    sc.Open();
    rows = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sc.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong:"+ex.Message);
}
if (rows < 1) // this should never happen without an exception - redundant
{
    MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong - no rows were inserted");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as other guys said ...
There are several options with this problem. You can use AddParameterWithValue method of SqlCommand.

1. Option with adding parameter;

   var sqlString = "INSERT INTO messages (messagetext,sentdate) values(@MesasgeText, @SentDate)"
   var messageText = bf.Deserialize(client).ToString();
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand scmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlString);
   scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MesasgeText", messageText);
   scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SentDate", DateTime.Now);
2. Option with encoding/decoding => If you will use this option don't forget to HtmlDecode when you will show you messageText to end user on website.

   var messageText = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(bf.Deserialize(client).ToString());

Hope this helps you,
Kind regards.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're coding it in C#?

If so it's probably because of the ' is a txt delimiter. I guess you could solve it by putting your escape character in there. It's probably(?) \ so the message should be "What\'s up" for it to not get an exception within your txt when using etc. '

You would still get an error when throwing it in SQL since ' there is also for defining start/stop in strings. To fix it there you need set double '

Etc 'What''s up!'

Comment: He is indeed using C#, but it has nothing to do with the client language used. You should simply use parameters. No developer really hard codes the values to place '' instead of '. Here in this case too it is message variable that is giving a grief which simply should be parameter. If he corrected it than likely would also need to handle the datetime value (that might work without giving any error but storing a wrong value - an unnoticed error is worse than an error).